# Storing foreign key value in database (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. i am having difficulties to store foreign key value in database. I have read the documentation, searched on stackoverflow. But its confusing me more.

I have a User table and an idea table. User can create many idea. Let me show the code:

**Controller function:**

```
 public function storePost(IdeaRequest $request) {
        Idea::create([
            'title' => $request->input('idea_title'),
            'user_id' => $request->hasMany('user_id'),
            'image' => $request->file('idea_image')->move('images'),
            'info' => $request->input('idea_info'),
            'communitySelection' => $request->input('selection'),
            'location' => $request->input('idea_location'),
            'goal' => $request->input('idea_goal'),
            'description' => $request->input('idea_description')
        ]);

    }
```

**Idea Model:**

```
class Idea extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'idea_title', 'idea_info','user_id', 'idea_image', 'idea_description', 'duration', 'idea_goal', 'pledge_amount', 'set_equity',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function Post() {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

**Idea Migration:**

```
  public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('ideas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('idea_title');
            $table->string('idea_info', 150);
            $table->string('idea_image');
            $table->string('selection');
            $table->longText('idea_description');
            $table->string('idea_location');
            $table->integer('idea_goal')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('pledge_amount')->unsigned();
            $table->string('set_equity')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**User Migration:**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',50);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password',32);
            $table->string('profile_picture')->nullable();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('phone_number',15);
            $table->boolean('status')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_type',15);
            $table->string('credit_card',16)->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

It can be seen that foreign key is being set. I am unable to store the value of foreign key on a user table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Idea Migration**, you can declare the foreign key like this

```
public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('ideas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('idea_title');
            $table->string('idea_info', 150);
            $table->string('idea_image');
            $table->string('selection');
            $table->longText('idea_description');
            $table->string('idea_location');
            $table->integer('idea_goal')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('pledge_amount')->unsigned();
            $table->string('set_equity')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        //Declare foreign key
        Schema::table('ideas', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('restrict')
                        ->onUpdate('restrict');
        });
    }
```

I do not agree with the relation you added in the **Idea Model**. You should use `belongsTo` instead of `hasMany`. And according to the comments, change `Post()` to User`()` .

```
public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

If so, you need also change `'user_id' => $request->hasMany('user_id')` in the **Controller function**.

Comment: I have declared the foreign key in another file. `Schema::table('ideas', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');`
        });` I am unable to understand; how to insert its value in database. Whenever i tried to submit form. it gives an error that cannot update child row

Comment: I must admit that the relation method name should be somthink like `user()` maybe, becasue `Post` dosen't match the logic.

Comment: I also agree that you should change Post() to user()

Comment: I do not understand `'user_id' => $request->hasMany('user_id')` in the **Controller function**.

Comment: I am so confused about this, i also thought that `'user_id' => $request->hasMany('user_id')` wont be there. i just removed it. changed Post() to User(). The question remains the same how do i store the values in Database ?.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your precious time. Have a look at error `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fundme`.`ideas`, CONSTRAINT `ideas_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `ideas` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2016-04-26 20:24:56, 2016-04-26 20:24:56))`

Comment: Maybe you mean `'user_id' => $request->input('user_id')` in the **Controller function**.

Comment: Error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null` When i changed `'user_id' => $request->hasMany('user_id')` to `'user_id' => $request->input('user_id')`. Is there anything to do with view? like having an `input field` for user_id ? Thanks

Comment: You'd better make sure that in the users table there exists a record  which has the user_id you are updating

Comment: Yes, you need have an input field for user_id in the view